# magento 2.4 change input field based on selcted country in shipping address form

Tags: checkout, magento2.4, custom-validation

I need to show/hide a magento input field (so NOT a custom field) based on the selected country in the shipping address form. Shipping address form is in two places: the customer account address book and the checkout > new shipping address popup page. So. for instance, the company field needs to be hidden for all countries except US, while for US country not only the company field must be visible but it needs to be required as well.

On the customer account form, my code works. I created a mixin for the `customer-address-validation` and added my code there:

```
requirejs-config.js

var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            addressValidation: {
                'Vendor_Module/js/view/customer-address-validation-mixin': true
            },
            'Magento_Customer/js/addressValidation': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/view/customer-address-validation-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};

customer-address-validation-mixin.js

[...]

if(countryId == countryCode) {
  this.companyInput.addClass('required-entry').attr('aria-required', true);
  this.companyContainer.addClass('required').show();
} else {
  this.companyInput.removeClass('required-entry').removeAttr('aria-required');
  this.companyContainer.removeClass('required').hide();
}

[...]
```

How can I apply the same code to the checkout shipping address form?

Answer (score 2):

Call a new JS on Checkout shipping address form

**File Path** : Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="my-custom-component" xsi:type="array">                                          
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/manageaddress</item>

                                </item>                                                          
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**JS File Path** : Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/manageaddress.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/url'
], function ($,url) {
    'use strict';
    var waitForE1 = function(selector, callback) {
        if ($(selector).length) {
           callback();
       } else {
          setTimeout(function() {
            waitForE1(selector, callback);
          }, 1000);
       }
    };
    $(document).on('change',"[name='country_id']",function(){
        
        var id = $("select[name='country_id']").val();
        if(id == 'usa'){
            $("input[name='company']").prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't work. On the console I get an error "cannot load the component"

Comment: My bad, I had a typo

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Naeem that pointed me to the right direction I was able to find a solution. I'm posting it here in case someone needs it.

- checkout_index_index.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="my-custom-field" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/my-component</item>
                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

- my-component.js:

```
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract'
], function (Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            imports: {
                update: 'checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress.shipping-address-fieldset.country_id:value'
            },
            modules: {
                myfield: '${ $.parentName }.my-custom-field'
            }
        },

        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            return this;
        },
        update: function (value) {
            if(value == "US") this.myfield().enable().show();
            else this.myfield().disable().hide();
        }
        
    });
});
```